# Is $ P \implies \lnot P $ consistent in zeroth-order logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In Zeroth-Order Logic, a formula is said to be consistent if it is TRUE under at least one valuation.

So I am checking if $ P \implies \lnot P $. Here is how it looks like:

For $ P = \text{TRUE}, $ we have $ P \implies \lnot P = \text{FALSE}.$

For $ P = \text{FALSE}, $ we have $ P \implies \lnot P = \text{TRUE}.$

So can we say that $ P \implies \lnot P $ is consistent?

If we can say this is consistent, then it somehow defies intuition, does it not? A proposition that implies the negation of it is impossible. Can you think of such a proposition? What am I missing?

Comment: You just derived that it is indeed consistent and that you have to consider a *false* evaluation of the propositional variable $P$.

Comment: Yes it is consistent, although not interesting as a propositional sentence. It’s equivalent to [(not $P$) or (not $P$)] which is trivially equivalent to (not $P$). The If-Then semantics in propositional logic and natural English are not identical, so unintuitive things do happen.

Comment: The proposition is not P.  It's (P$\rightarrow$$\lnot$P).  I don't see how that *implication* defies intuition, no.

Comment: Let P = "A is false". Then $P \to \lnot P$ reads: "if A is false, then not-A is true". Nothing defying intuition...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, not only is $P$ being false a valuation that sets this statement to True, but you can easily show that this statement is logically *equivalent* to $\neg P$:

$$P \to \neg P \overset{Implication}{\Leftrightarrow} \neg P \lor \neg P \overset{Idempotence}{\Leftrightarrow} \neg P$$

I believe the feeling that it defies intuition that this statement would be consistent stems from the fact that it feels there is some contradiction within thois statement ... and indeed: *if* you assume that $P$ is True, then that would mean that $\neg P$ is True as well, and hence the contradiction. However, all that that really means is that $P$ apparently cannot be True. Hence, it needs to be False.  So, what this statement *implies* is that $P$ has to be False, i.e. $\neg P$. And as it turns out, it is in fact equivalent to it.